# pymongo MongoClient without replicaSet parameter

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have three mongo nodes which I specify in the url which I use in the MongoClient. It looks something like this "mongodb://A,B,C,D". I need the read preference as Secondary, for which I used SECONDARY_PREFERRED. Everything works as expected, I am able to connect to the secondary node without any problem. I get the connection using -
mongo_con = MongoClient(db_url, read_Preference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED)

I was wondering what the impact is if I don't send the 'replicaSet' optional parameter while getting the connection. What will be the difference in the connection, in case I use the repicaSet and send the correct replica set name, what if I send an incorrect replica set name? How will it impact my connection?

Comment: How about you try and figure out?

Comment: As I said, I tried it and it works fine. I wanted to know the long-term impact. I cannot just "figure out" without it taking many weeks and observing the behavior and corner cases. Thanks for the valuable suggestion though.

Comment: It should not make any difference. The server (mongo node) you connect to knows about the replica-set that it is connected to.

Comment: So the use of the replicaSet parameter is only when I specify just the primary node in the url I use in the MongoClient? I just observed people using the replicaSet parameter sometimes and wasn't sure about the broader impact of it.

Comment: Admittedly this question (at least the first half of it) is pretty much impossible to  "figure out" without reading the driver's source code.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering what the impact is if I don't send the 'replicaSet' optional parameter while getting the connection.

This depends on the driver (pymongo/node etc.) you are using and how many seeds you specify in the connection string.

When given a single seed, some drivers assume you want a direct connection to that server only and some drivers discover the topology of the deployment and, if it is a replica set, would discover all of the other nodes and "connect to the replica set".

The behavior is currently being standardized across drivers via the `directConnection` URI option.

When you provide `replicaSet` URI option, you are forcing the second behavior of discovering the replica set in all drivers. Providing multiple seeds also works as long as you are not in a single-node replica set.

> What will be the difference in the connection, in case I use the repicaSet and send the correct replica set name, what if I send an incorrect replica set name? How will it impact my connection?

If you specify `replicaSet` and give an incorrect set name, the driver will filter out all servers that have the correct set name (or from the driver's perspective, your instructed `replicaSet` is the correct one and the one reported by servers would be wrong). Your application will fail to find any usable servers.